# Append Pub file to other MS Publisher 2010 file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-automation, publisher, ms-publisher

In MS Publisher 2010, you can add a PUB file (a catalog publication which merge a template with data coming from Excel file) to the end of an existing pub file. 
Quite convenient to compose a Catalog book. I can do it by hand with Publisher user interface and I would like to automate this task (there is 26 chapters).

Unfortunately, I was not able to locate the automation function, neither a simple example.
Did someone could help me with some automation sample for this task?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the Publisher interop library with PowerShell?

This is how I'd go about it if so (untested C#, but it should give you an idea of how to go about it if you read up on it in [MSDN's Publisher VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861522.aspx)):

```
Publisher.Application firstPubApp = new Publisher.Application(); //open a new publisher instance
Publisher.Document sourcePublication = firstPubApp.Open("sourcefile.pub"); //open your publisher document

Publisher.Application otherPubApp = new Publisher.Application();
Publisher.Document targetPublication = otherPubApp.Open("targetfile.pub");
targetPublication.Pages.Add(1, 1); //add one page after page 1

foreach (Publisher.Shape shape in sourcePublication.Pages[1].Shapes) //loop through all pages on page 1
{
    shape.Copy(); //copy the shape
    otherPubApp.ActiveDocument.Pages[2].Shapes.Paste(); //paste it in the other document
}
```

It is quite possible that a better way to do it than looping through all shapes on all pages is hidden somewhere in that documentation though. It's always hard to find samples for Publisher compared to Excel or Word.